# Override center tag with css

Tags: html, css

I am using Stylebot, which adds CSS properties with `!important` to websites. The page looks like this:

```
<article class="main" id="contentDetail"> 
  <center>
    <img src="example.png"> 
  </center> 
...
```

Is it possible to add CSS properties to override the `<center>` tag and have the image align left? I have tried `align="left"`. Stylebot does not seem to be able to remove the tag.

Comment: What about `center { text-align: left; }` ?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Oh that was easy. Can you post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the [`text-align` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align). In this case:

```
center {
  text-align: left;
}
```

The default user-agent stylesheet sets it to center by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:left;` on `center` like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue

```
center{
display: inline;
}
```